# How do I add synonyms to system entity in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am a novice in dialogflow.

I am exploring options building a bot with dialogflow where a user enters an item an its ordering quantity as shown below

Cashewnuts 2 kg

Dialogflow provides a system entity (@sys.unit-weight )which will readily identify this. But the user not necessarily enters in the same way every time. instead of Cashewnuts 2 Kg, he may enter cashewnuts 2 kilo or cashewnuts 2 Kgs or  cashewnuts 2 Kilograms.

In all these case, the user really mean Cashewnuts 2 kg.

Now, there should be someway where I define Kg ( which is in @sys.unit-weight entity) synonyms as (Kgs, Kilograms, kilo etc.) Where should I do that.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Dialogflow sys.unit-weight already detects kilograms, kilo, kgs, etc. If it doesn't try the following: write something that its recognized by the entity then change it manually by rewriting like so:

[image]

Then press Save. Usually it will be saved as a synonym for @sys.unit-weight